# debug calls from mobile applications to webservices

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I need to debug an mobile application and the webservice calls it is making.

**What is the easiest way to debug calls from mobile applications to webservices?**

I remember there was a site which proxied calls to webservices and displayed all the call information, but I can't remember the name of it. The Azure mobile services team were using it at Build.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a website name.

Comment: @SonerGönül Have updated

Comment: @tdelepine The calls are coming from the mobile device though, and not going through my desktop machine

Comment: have you access to the server or it's a cloud machine ?

Comment: @tdelepine It's deployed on azurewebsites at the moment. I have seen a website / service which works as a proxy for debugging mobile calls, a few of the guys at build were using it

Comment: It seem that Windows Azure application by using the Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio exists for debugging, but i never used it

Comment: @tdelepine In case you are interested I found the service I had seen - http://www.runscope.net

Comment: Yes i'm interested. My customers use a Web App and a WCF Services lodge in azurewebsites.

Comment: @tdelepine Well I've just been trying it, seems good, is free too as long as you don't do too many requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the service I was looking for

https://www.runscope.com

> In order for Runscope to capture traffic you need to direct it through
>   our gateway. This is accomplished with special Runscope URLs that
>   contain the target API host name along with your bucket key.
>
> The basic formula for creating a Runscope URL is:
>
> Start with the scheme and hostname of the target API. For this example
>   we'll use https://api.yourapihere.com. Replace the dots with dashes.
>   If the hostname has dashes, double them up. Append a dash, your bucket
>   key and runscope.net. We now have
>   https://api-yourapihere-com-cawa10y5hiwi.runscope.net. From your code
>   or other HTTP client, execute the API call with the Runscope URL you
>   created. The path, headers, request data and URL querystring
>   parameters do not need to change.

Comment: That's a great service, thanks for sharing. The "rewrite the URL" thing is slightly more intrusive in your debug code base than a simple "set this proxy", but the advantages of not having to poke NAT/firewall holes from the mobile network to your developer machine are obvious!

Answer (score 1):

You usually setup a debug build in your mobile application, where internet calls are proxied through Fiddler running on your desktop machine. This is a very powerful and convenient way of debugging webservice calls from a mobile app.

However, this requires a development environment and http library with the ability to explicitly set a proxy address. Or a mobile OS that has the option to set a global proxy on all connections.

Comment: I have found http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy .. I have seen a site which allows you to proxy calls without the need for a local proxy, which would have the benefit of viewing being able to view calls made from clients who could not connect to my machine. The guys from the mobile services team at Azure were using it at Build.

Comment: I found the it in the end - http://www.runscope.net